# mod_rewrite to direct site.com/something to index.php?values=something

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

(I might be an idiot, it appears that .htaccess isn't enabled by default in Apache on OSX.)

I know there are a lot of mod_rewrite questions out there, but I just can't get mine right and nothing else seems to quite cover it.

All I want to do is redirect

```
www.url.com/something
```

or

```
www.url.com/something/anything/more
```

to

```
www.url.com/index.php?values=something
```

or

```
www.url.com/index.php?values=something/anything/more
```

Nothing fancier than that (I'll put in something about ignoring gif/jpg/png, adding www. etc later later) - all processing of something/anything/more will be done in PHP.

I just can't get it right though. Any hints/resources or anyone who's just managed to do this? It's more frustrating knowing that I once got it absolutely perfect but lost that code years ago.

Comment: RewriteRule ^.$ /index.php?page=$1 [L] among others - I tried a "work it through from the manual" myself but it didn't work so I assumed it was me and tried some ready-made ones, but I can't get them working either

Comment: It was definitely a problem with .htaccess not being enabled on OSX. I'm still having problems (403 errors even though I've changed the AllowOverride setting in both httpd.conf and username.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, at least in what you are asking But basically you need to make index.php passthrough (so you don't rewrite index.php *to* index.php), then the main rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php - [L]

# your conditions here
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?values=$1 [L]
```

Add whatever conditions you want to exclude rewrite at the `# your conditions here` spot

Comment: Trying this at the moment (having seemingly solved the .htaccess not working problem) and I get a 404 index.php not found when accessing any URL other than index.php directly.

Comment: @JonStory where is index.php? How are you accessing index.php directly? Is this htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: index.php is in the same directory as the .htaccess which is /Users/Jon/Sites/websitedirectory/ in the OSX file system. The error is The requested URL /Users/jon/Sites/websitedirectory/index.php was not found on this server, which I've just realised is different to the normal 404 listing The requested URL /~jon/websitedirectory/blahblah was not found on this server which I normally get. Is this a directory problem?

Comment: @JonStory If it's in the same directory, maybe let the file-path work itself out by removing the leading `/` in the rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?values=$1 [L]`. Other than that, I have no idea why the file-path is getting mixed up with URI-path. You may also want to try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~jon/websitedirectory/index.php?values=$1 [L]` to explicitly give it a URI-path.

Comment: It works if I give it the full URL (including http://machine.local/ or http://localhost/), but neither of those suggestions work :( the fact I can get it working at all is encouraging, it just means I might have to use separate .htaccess files for test and production servers which is a pain. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?values=$1 [L]
```

Please note that you need to have AllowOverride On set in the Apache host config file for the directory in question if you are trying to do this in an .htaccess file and of course need to have mod_rewrite module enabled.

This rule will ignore the redirect for any actual files or directories (i.e. images) that actually exist (including index.php).

Comment: ...I might be an idiot. Using apache in OSX and assumed that I could just use .htaccess off the bat. I don't think it's activated by default. One of those days.

Comment: @JonStory Well in your comment above it seems you were also trying `/.$` as your regex, which would a) only work for URI's that are one character long (since you didn't have * indicating 0 to many many characters) and b) would not have captured anything to populate into $1, as you didn't have parenthesis around it